# Function for binary conversion

Tags: c, function, binary

I am trying to convert a decimal value to binary using the function I wrote in C below. I cannot figure out the reason why it is printing 32 zeroes rather than the binary value of 2.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <limits.h>

int binaryConversion(int num){
    int bin_buffer[32];
    int mask = INT_MIN;
    for(int i = 0; i < 32; i++){
        if(num & mask){
            bin_buffer[i] = 1;
            mask >> 1;
        }
        else{
            bin_buffer[i] = 0;
            mask >> 1;
        }
    }
    for(int j = 0; j < 32; j++){
        printf("%d", bin_buffer[j]);
    }
}


int main(){
    binaryConversion(2);
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two mistakes:

1. You use `>>` instead of `>>=`, so you're not actually ever changing `mask`.
2. You didn't declare `mask` as `unsigned`, so when you shift, it'll get sign-extended, which you don't want.

Comment: Yep, that's about it. Might as well move `mask >>= 1;` outside the `if` block since it will be executed regardless.

Comment: Mistake #3:  `INT_MIN` might have more than one bit set.  Common values for `INT_MIN` only have one bit set, but the smallest magnitude value for `INT_MIN` is 32767.

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm: yes, it *can,* but this tends to be on environments that have ones complement or sign-magnitude encoding for negative numbers, which are few and far between. C++ has already opted to insist on twos complement in C++20 and ISO C is considering the same move. Hopefully we'll be rid of those wierd encoding at some point :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you put a:

```
printf("%d %d\n", num, mask);
```

immediately inside your `for` loop, you'll see why:

```
2 -2147483648
2 -2147483648
2 -2147483648
2 -2147483648
:
2 -2147483648
```

The expression `mask >> 1` *does* right shift the value of `mask` but doesn't actually assign it back to `mask`. I think you *meant* to use:

```
mask >>= 1;
```

---

On top of that (once you fix that problem), you'll see that the values in the mask are a bit strange because right-shifting a negative value can preserve the sign, meaning you will end up with *multiple* bits set.

You'd be better off using unsigned integers since the `>>` operator will act on them more in line with your expectations.

---

Additionally, there's little point in writing all those bits into a buffer just so you can print them out later. Unless you need to do some manipulation on the bits (and this appears to not be the case here), you can just output them directly as they're calculated (and get rid of the now unnecessary `i` variable).

---

So, taking all those points into account, you can *greatly* simplify your code such as with the following complete program:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

int binaryConversion(unsigned num) {
    for (unsigned mask = (unsigned)INT_MIN; mask != 0; mask >>= 1)
        putchar((num & mask) ? '1' : '0');
}

int main(void) {
    binaryConversion(2);
    putchar('\n');
}
```

---

And just one more note, the value of `INT_MIN` is not actually required to just have the top bit set. Because of the current allowance by C to handle ones' complement and sign-magnitude (as well as two's complement) for negative numbers, it possible for INT_MIN to have a value with multiple bits set (such as `-32767`).

There are moves afoot to remove these little-used encodings from C (C++20 has already flagged this) but, for maximum portability, you could opt instead for the following function:

```
int binaryConversion(unsigned int num) {
    // Done once to set topBit.

    static unsigned topBit = 0;
    if (topBit == 0) {
        topBit = 1;
        while (topBit << 1 != 0) topBit <<= 1;
    }

    // Loop to process all bits.

    for (unsigned mask = topBit; mask != 0; mask >>= 1)
        putchar(num & mask ? '1' : '0');
}
```

This calculates the value with the top bit set the first time you call the function, irrespective of the vagaries of negative encodings. Just watch out if you call it concurrently in a threaded program.

But, as mentioned, this probably isn't necessary, the number of environments that use the other two encodings would be countable on the fingers of a *very* careless/unlucky industrial machine operator.

Answer (score 0):

You already have your primary question answered regarding the use of `>>` rather than `=>>`. However, from a fundamental standpoint there is no need to buffer the `1` and `0` in an array of `int` (e.g. `int bin_buffer[32];`) and there is no need to use the `variadic` `printf` function to display `int` values if all you are doing is outputting the binary representation of the number.

Instead, all you need is `putchar()` to output `'1'` or `'0'` depending on whether any bit is set or clear. You can also make your output function a bit more useful by providing the size of the representation you want, e.g. a `byte` (8-bits), a `word` (16-bits), and so on.

For example, you could do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <limits.h>

/** binary representation of 'v' padded to 'sz' bits.
 *  the padding amount is limited to the number of
 *  bits in 'v'. valid range: 0 - sizeof v * CHAR_BIT.
 */
void binaryConversion (const unsigned long v, size_t sz)
{
    if (!sz) { fprintf (stderr, "error: invalid sz.\n"); return; }
    if (!v)  { while (sz--) putchar ('0'); return; }

    if (sz > sizeof v * CHAR_BIT)
        sz = sizeof v * CHAR_BIT;

    while (sz--)
        putchar ((v >> sz & 1) ? '1' : '0');
}

int main(){
    fputs ("byte : ", stdout);
    binaryConversion (2, 8);
    fputs ("\nword : ", stdout);
    binaryConversion (2, 16);
    putchar ('\n');
}
```

Which allows you to set the number of bits you want displayed, e.g.

**Example Use/Output**

```
$ ./bin/binaryconversion
byte : 00000010
word : 0000000000000010
```

There is nothing wrong with your approach, but there may be a simpler way to arrive at the same output.

Let me know if you have further questions.

Answer (score 0):

`INT_MIN` is a negative number so when you shifted to the right using `>>`, the most significant bit will still be `1` instead of zero and you will end up in `mask=11111...111` all bits have value of `1`. Also the `mask` value is not changing. better use `>>=` instead. You can try masking on `0x1` and shift the actual value of `num` instead of the `mask` like this.

```
int binaryConversion(int num) {
    char bin_buffer[32 + 1];  //+1 for string terminator.
    int shifted = num;
    for (int i = 31; i >= 0; --i, shifted >>= 1) {  //loop 32x
        bin_buffer[i] = '0' + (shifted & 0x1);
    }
    bin_buffer[32] = 0;  //terminate the string.

    printf("%s", bin_buffer);

}
```