# Program to convert octal to binary number system

Tags: c

i am a beginner in c programing language and in this few days i'm train to do some c exercises 
and i get stucked in some exercice for conversions:
so this is what i had did

```
#include <stdio.h>

#include <string.h>

int main() {

    int num[8] = {
        0,
        1,
        2,
        3,
        4,
        5,
        6,
        7
    };
    long long binary, octal, tempoctal;
    int last, i, A, tempi;
    char hex[9] = {
        '000',
        '001',
        '010',
        '011',
        '100',
        '101',
        '110',
        '111'
    };
    int bex[10];
    A = 0;

    printf("enter an octal number:  ");
    scanf("%lld", & octal);

    tempoctal = octal;

    while (tempoctal != 0) {
        last = tempoctal % 10;

        for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
            if (num[i] == last) {
                tempi = i;
                bex[A] = tempi;

            }
        }

        A++;
        tempoctal /= 10;
    }

    printf("\nthe is %s", bex);

    return 0;
}
```

so i want just to know why when i want to print the array of bex 
i get error on the consol [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6laoC.png).
Although i know the solution but i want to do it in my own way.

Comment: *I get error on the consol* is not a problem description. What *error* do you get? It's *on the consol* right in front of you, but we can't see your screen from here. Your post should include a clear problem description, including the **exact** error message you're seeing, and ask a **specific question** related to the code you've posted. Please see [ask] and [mcve].

Comment: Once you store `scanf("%lld", & octal);`, the bits in memory are the same whether you want to look at it in binary, octal, decimal or hex -- the bits don't change. Why not simply iterate over `octal` bitwise and output the bits? What makes you think you can print `bex` as a string? `printf("\nthe is %s", bex);` when you have `int bex[10];`??

Comment: You are invoking *Undefined Behavior* using a `printf` *conversion specifier* that does not match the argument given. See [printf(3) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/printf.3.html) and [C11 §7.21.6.1(p2 & p9) The fprintf function - insufficient arguments, or incorrect type.](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#7.21.6.1p9). You will also benefit from the answer here [Function for binary conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993842/function-for-binary-conversion/54994017#54994017)

Comment: the code should be uncompilable, due to the fact that you have used character literals with three characters on them.  Didn't you get a compilation error from that?

Comment: Do you know you have a `%o` octal specifier to read a number in base 8?   Why do you read it in base 10 ???

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, please, don't invoke U.B. with a newcomer.  This is not going to help.  Also the standard references are most probably not understandable for a newcomer to C.  Try to be more friendly and cite less the standard, nobody is writing a compiler in this question.  I don't believe the standard is the right place to look for _new to C_ info.

Comment: Was the [Function for binary conversion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54993842/function-for-binary-conversion/54994017#54994017) at least helpful?

Comment: Probably not.  You have enumerated a so huge amount of references that he will be unable to find the right one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answering your question. `bex` is declared as `int bex[10]`, array of integers. `printf("%s"...` expects a character string, not an array of int.

- A character string is usually an array of chars `char bex[10]`. Char is a single byte, and an int is usually 4-byte long. So, you see the difference there. In your example you modify the lowest byte of the 'int', leaving other 3 as '0'.
- printable chars  have corresponding codes. For example a char of '0' has code of `48` in asccii encoding. All other chars that represent numbers have consecutive codes (48..57). This how the `printf` and other services know what to print if they see `48` in the byte.
- the string in 'c' ends with a stray `0`, so that the `printf` knows where to stop reading the chars.

So, if you want to print 'bex' as a string, you need to create it as a string. for example

```
char bex[10];

 for (i=0; i <8; i++)
     bex[A++] = '0' + i; // code of '0' + a number
 bex[A] = 0; // string terminator
```

Just make sure that your 'A' is always less than '8' to avoid  array overflow (string length of 9  plus one character for the terminator. Now you can do this.

```
 printf("%s", bex);
```

You have to work on the rest of the program, because it does not do anything useful in the current state, but this should help you to get going.